# How to know if a byte array is a valid image

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays, android-image

Is there a way to know if a byte array is a valid image?

I am taking a photograph, In OnActivityResult:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, out);
//arrayFotos is an ArrayList
arrayFotos.add(new BeanFotos("", imageBitmap, lastKnwonLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnwonLocation.getLongitude()));
```

I am storing it in database:

```
//listaFotos and arrayFotos are the same array, but with different names, because I am storing it in another class in my app
for(int i=0;i<listaFotos.size();i++){
values.clear();
values.put("codficha", codficha);
int bytes=listaFotos.get(i).getFoto().getByteCount();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
listaFotos.get(i).getFoto().copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
values.put("foto", buffer.array());
db.insert("fotos", null, values);
}
```

Later, I need that image to be shown:

```
byte[] arrayFoto = csr2.getBlob(0);
Bitmap fotoBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arrayFoto, 0, arrayFoto.length);
```

The problem is, no matter what i do, the decodeByteArray method always returns null. I have tried with external libraries, and it is always null, so I am thinking maybe I am storing it in the wrong way. The arrayFoto variable is NOT null, I am receiving bytes (84584, to be exact) but the decodeByteArray method returns null.

So, is there a way for me to be sure that the byte array is a correct image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are writing the uncompressed Bitmap to the database. You need to compress it to jpeg or png first if you want to be able to decode it using `BitmapFactory`.

Also, storing images in a database is a bad idea since the cursor window size is limited to 1MB. You should not store binary data in a SQLite db unless it's very small.

Comment: Tried to store it in Base64 format, but disabled it to test if it was the problem. Also, I am storing the image compressed to JPEG format, and then getting the bytes from it. I am adding the image to a static ArrayList, once it is compressed, and later I am accessing that static ArrayList from the class where I save data to database.

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure your `listaFotos` list contains `Bitmap`s in `getFoto()` and not compressed image files. `Bitmap`s are uncompressed images and you copy the raw bytes straight to the database using `Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer()` which is why you can't decode it back. Also, because it's uncompressed, it takes even more space. For example, an uncompressed image of 640x480 pixels in RGBA_8888 format takes about 1,2 Megabytes which is huge.

Comment: To resume: to fix it you should copy the bytes of the original file to your DB, not the decoded Bitmap bytes. Even though I suggest you to avoid storing big binary data in a database; it's better to keep images in files (instead you could store the image file name in the database for example). And Base64 is even worse than binary because it increases the file size by 33% (Base64 encodes groups of 3 bytes to 4 ASCII bytes).

Comment: I think I will finally store the path to file in database instead of the file. So much less pain that way. Thank you!